# Is there a way to place a comment in a file which vim will process in order to set filetype?

Tags: vim

For example, if I want to have a file with the name `gitconfig` (no leading `.`) be recognised by vim as being of `filetype=gitconfig`, is there a means of indicating this in a comment or something similar within the file itself? Note, I want this to work across systems, so modifying vim's startup files is not preferred.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

This sounds like the `modeline` feature (see the on-line help).  In gitconfig you could have a modeline like the following, near the beginning or end of the file:

```
# vi: ft=gitconfig
```

This requires modelines to be enabled and since they can be a security hazard they are disabled by default on many systems though.

Another approach which might be slightly more work is to make a `.vim` file containing

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile */gitconfig setfiletype gitconfig
```

and drop it in `~/.vim/ftdetect` on all your systems.

Comment: Perfect, modeline is what I was looking for. modeline is enabled, but it looks like something else in my setup is interfering with it. If I put your suggested line at the top of the file, then after I reopen it `set filetype?` reveals filetype 'conf'.

Comment: Maybe you can use `:verbose set filetype` to see where the `conf` value comes from - I would guess vim's system default filetype settings somewhere.

Comment: apparently it was last set from /usr/share/vim/vim73/filetype.vim. Why would system level filetype detection override the directive I've placed in the file itself?

Comment: were you running vim as root? if yes, I think the modeline wouldn't load.

Comment: Also check the value of the `modelines` option. `:set modelines?` If it's set to zero, it won't process the modeline.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a syntax file and put it in vim's `share/syntax` directory (on Debian Lenny it's `/usr/share/vim/vim71/syntax` (your distro may vary)).

Documentation on Vim's syntax format is here: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html

You may be able to find a ready syntax file on the Internet somewhere, but I'll leave that as an exercise for you.