# Setting vim filetype with modeline not working as expected

Tags: vim, osx

As per the accepted answer to this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19867/is-there-a-way-to-place-a-comment-in-a-file-which-vim-will-process-in-order-to-se), I'm attempting to use modelines in vim to force filetype detection in some files.

For example, at the top of a file named `gitconfig` (note there is no leading `.`), I have the following line:

```
# vim: set filetype=gitconfig :
```

`modeline` is enabled on my system. However, when I open the file in vim, `set filetype?` returns `conf`, rather than the expected `gitconfig`.

Is it possible that other parts of my vim configuration (e.g. filetype.vim) are causing this strange behaviour?

Edited in response to comments:

`set compatible?` returns `nocompatible`

`set modeline?` returns `modeline`

`verbose set filetype?` returns:

```
filetype=conf
      Last set from /usr/share/vim/vim73/filetype.vim
```

I don't understand why the system wide filetype plugin would be overriding what I have set in the file itself.

One final note: this is the version of Vim 7.3 shipped with OSX.

The latest version of [MacVim](http://code.google.com/p/macvim) running on the same system using the same `.vimrc` behaves as expected, with `set ft?` returning `filetype=gitconfig`.

Comment: I usually saw those options set at the *end* (last line) of files - maybe that is the issue...

Comment: Just to make sure: did you *check* that `set modeline?` does not print `nomodeline`?

Comment: I find the most common cause for modeline not working is that `compatible` is set. That would be worth checking too.

Comment: See updated question for responses.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

So, after some digging, it transpires that the system `vimrc` shipped with OSX sets the `modelines` (note the trailing 's') variable to 0. This variable controls the number of lines in a file which are checked for set commands. Setting modelines to a non-zero value in my `.vimrc` solved the problem.

Full output, for the curious: the output of `vim --version` prompted me to check the system vimrc:

```
% vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Jun 24 2011 20:00:09)
Compiled by root@apple.com
Normal version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
...
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0 -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -Os -pipe
Linking: gcc -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -o vim -lncurses
```

Looking at the system vimrc:

```
% cat /usr/share/vim/vimrc 
" Configuration file for vim
set modelines=0         " CVE-2007-2438
...
```

Led me to the `modelines` variable. It appears that MacVim does not source this system file (perhaps looking for a system GVIMRC instead? `:help startup` isn't clear).

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Jul 27 2011 19:46:24)
MacOS X (unix) version
Included patches: 1-260
Compiled by XXXXX
Huge version with MacVim GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
...
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  system gvimrc file: "$VIM/gvimrc"
    user gvimrc file: "$HOME/.gvimrc"
    system menu file: "$VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_MACVIM -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -p
ipe  -DMACOS_X_UNIX -no-cpp-precomp  -g -O2 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1
Linking: gcc   -L.         -Wl,-syslibroot,/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -L/usr/local/lib -o V
im -framework Cocoa -framework Carbon      -lncurses  -liconv -framework Cocoa    -fstack-prote
ctor -L/usr/local/lib  -L/System/Library/Perl/5.10/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE -lperl -lm -
lutil -lc -framework Python   -framework Ruby
```

Answer (score 4):

For this to work on my macOS system I had to define a couple of settings in ~/.vimrc:

```
modeline
modelines=2
```

Where '**modeline**' enables the use of in-file settings, and '**modelines=#**' sets the number of lines that vim/vi will check for set commands.

Once those parameters were set I was able to use syntax like the line below in my files to override set parameters.

```
# vim: ts=4 sw=4 ai
```